# How do I know the appropriate number of iterations when using Miceforest for imputation?

Tags: python, random-forest, preprocessing, data-imputation, lightgbm

I want to know how to avoid overfitting without having to increase the number of iterations excessively in Python with the Miceforest library.  I know you can make a correlation map of data sets but I feel that overfitting can occur.  The data I am handling is categorical.